# Class 'Spatie\Activitylog\ActivitylogFacade' not found in activity log in laravel 7.1

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, package, activitylog

I have installed spatie laravel activity log package but it is giving this error
I am following this documentation  https://github.com/spatie/activitylog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository was updated 4 years ago and not compatible with `Laravel7`. Instead you can use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

> This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.

[image]